# spinner fatalexception: asynctask #2 an error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-spinner

i create chain spinner that get data from server and return it by json.  my firts spinner is fine. in second spinner the json give response but when try to save the renspone in array the asynctask error caused by nullpointerexception. when i check it in log cat there is no null in my json response. so i try to change name of array with same name as first spinner there is no error but the second spinner show same value as first spinner.
my question why my second spinner when name of array different from first spinner is error ? 
where is the nullpointerexception error because when i check it there is no null ?   how to fixed it ?

there is my LoginActivity.java

```
// Email, password edittext
EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
private static String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
private String URL_LOGIN = "http://api.omidev.com/login/format/json";
private String URL_PROV = "http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/provinsi/format/json";
private String URL_KOTA = null;
private Spinner spinnerProv, spinnerKota, spinnerKec, spinnerDesa;
// array list for spinner adapter
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesListKota;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
HttpPost httppost;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String mSelected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());   
    main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
    login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLogin);
    regis = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutRegister);

    // Email, Password input text
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    getActionBar().hide();
    ubahTulisan();
}

private void ubahTulisan()
{
    // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/roboto_black.ttf";

    // text view label
    TextView txtMasuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView txtAkunBaru = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    txtMasuk.setTypeface(tf);
    txtAkunBaru.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void login_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void regis_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(1);
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    spinnerProv = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinnerKota = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinnerKec = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);
    spinnerDesa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner4);
    // spinner item select listener
    spinnerProv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            try {
                mSelected = URLEncoder.encode(categoriesList.get(position).getId().toString(), "utf-8");
                URL_KOTA ="http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/kota/id/"+mSelected+"/format/json";
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //new GetKota().execute();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                            mSelected + " Selected" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new GetKota().execute();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    // spinner item select listener
    new GetCategories().execute();
}

public void login_cancel_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(1);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void regis_cancel_click(View view)
{       
    main.setVisibility(1);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void login_accept_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);

    new Login().execute();

}

public void regis_accept_click(View view)
{

    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Validating User..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {

        String username = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
        // Preparing post params
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();

        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_LOGIN,
                ServiceHandler.POST, params);

        Log.d("Create Response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                // checking for error node in json
                if (jsonObj.getString(KEY_LOGIN) != null) { 
                    // new category created successfully
                    JSONArray menuitemArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("login");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
                        String id = menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_user").toString();
                        String email = menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("email").toString();
                        session.createLoginSession(""+id, ""+email.toString());
                    }
                    // Staring MainActivity
                    Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                    finish();

                } 

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Email Atau Password Salah", false);
                    }
                }); 
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        }else{
            // user didn't entered username or password
            // Show alert asking him to enter the details
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Masukan Email dan Password", false);
                }
            }); 
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerProv.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

private void populateSpinnerKota() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesListKota.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesListKota.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerKota.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_PROV, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("lokasi");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getString("id_provinsi"),
                                catObj.getString("nama"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateSpinner();
    }

}

private class GetKota extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_KOTA, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categorieskota = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("lokasi");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categorieskota.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categorieskota.get(i);
                        Log.e("Response Kota: ", "> " + catObj.getString("id_kota"));
                        Category catK = new Category(catObj.getString("id_kota"),
                                catObj.getString("nama"));
                        categoriesListKota.add(catK);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateSpinnerKota();
    }

}
```

my category.java

```
private String id;
private String name;

public Category(){}

public Category(String id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
```

my serviceHandler.java

```
static InputStream is = null;
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    return response;

}
```

This is `Logcat` error:

```
02-05 18:20:48.953: E/Response:(29903): > {"lokasi":[{"id_provinsi":"1","nama":"Bali"},{"id_provinsi":"2","nama":"Banten"},{"id_provinsi":"3","nama":"Bengkulu"},{"id_provinsi":"4","nama":"DI Yogyakarta"},{"id_provinsi":"5","nama":"DKI Jakarta"},{"id_provinsi":"6","nama":"Gorontalo"},{"id_provinsi":"7","nama":"Irian Jaya Barat"},{"id_provinsi":"8","nama":"Jambi"},{"id_provinsi":"9","nama":"Jawa Barat"},{"id_provinsi":"10","nama":"Jawa Tengah"},{"id_provinsi":"11","nama":"Jawa Timur"},{"id_provinsi":"12","nama":"Kalimantan Barat"},{"id_provinsi":"13","nama":"Kalimantan Selatan"},{"id_provinsi":"14","nama":"Kalimantan Tengah"},{"id_provinsi":"15","nama":"Kalimantan Timur"},{"id_provinsi":"16","nama":"Kep. Bangka Belitung"},{"id_provinsi":"17","nama":"Kep. Riau"},{"id_provinsi":"18","nama":"Lampung"},{"id_provinsi":"19","nama":"Maluku"},{"id_provinsi":"20","nama":"Maluku Utara"},{"id_provinsi":"21","nama":"Nanggroe Aceh Darussalaam"},{"id_provinsi":"22","nama":"Nusa Tenggara Barat"},{"id_provinsi":"23","nama":"Nusa Tenggara Timur"},{"id_provinsi":"24","nama":"Papua"},{"id_provinsi":"25","nama":"Riau"},{"id_provinsi":"26","nama":"Sulawesi Selatan"},{"id_provinsi":"27","nama":"Sulawesi Tengah"},{"id_provinsi":"28","nama":"Sulawesi Tenggara"},{"id_provinsi":"29","nama":"Sulawesi Utara"},{"id_provinsi":"30","nama":"Sumatra Barat"},{"id_provinsi":"31","nama":"Sumatra Selatan"},{"id_provinsi":"32","nama":"Sumatra Utara"}]}
02-05 18:20:49.573: E/Response:(29903): > {"lokasi":[{"id_kota":"1","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN BADUNG"},{"id_kota":"2","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN BANGLI"},{"id_kota":"3","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN BULELENG"},{"id_kota":"4","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN GIANYAR"},{"id_kota":"5","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN JEMBRANA"},{"id_kota":"6","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN KARANG ASEM"},{"id_kota":"7","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN KLUNGKUNG"},{"id_kota":"8","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KABUPATEN TABANAN"},{"id_kota":"9","id_provinsi":"1","nama":"KOTA DENPASAR"}]}
02-05 18:20:49.573: E/Response Kota:(29903): > 1
02-05 18:20:49.573: W/dalvikvm(29903): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415b1360)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at com.android.desaku.LoginActivity$GetKota.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:377)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at com.android.desaku.LoginActivity$GetKota.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-05 18:20:49.603: E/AndroidRuntime(29903):    ... 5 more
```

please help me thanks. sorry i dont know how to post logcat

Comment: remove  `startActivity(a); finish();` from `InBackground`

Comment: not that login asynctask but in getKota asynctask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my fault. i already fixed my code
in `GetKota Asynctask` i did not initialized `categoriesListKota`, so that make it error caused by nullpointerexception.
to make the second spinning change when selected value from first spinning i add `notifyDataSetChanged()` to change the spinner adapter on `populateSpinnerKota()` and `clear()` on `GetKota Asynctask` to make the spinner clean from previous data.

this is the correct code for LoginActivity.java

```
// Alert Dialog Manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

// Email, password edittext
EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
private static String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
private String URL_LOGIN = "http://api.omidev.com/login/format/json";
private String URL_PROV = "http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/provinsi/format/json";
private String URL_KOTA = null;
private Spinner spinnerProv, spinnerKota, spinnerKec, spinnerDesa;
// array list for spinner adapter
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesListKota = new ArrayList<Category>();
ProgressDialog pDialog;
HttpPost httppost;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String mSelected;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Session Manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());   
    main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
    login = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutLogin);
    regis = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutRegister);

    // Email, Password input text
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
    getActionBar().hide();
    ubahTulisan();
}

private void ubahTulisan()
{
    // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/roboto_black.ttf";

    // text view label
    TextView txtMasuk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView txtAkunBaru = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    txtMasuk.setTypeface(tf);
    txtAkunBaru.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void login_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void regis_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(1);

    spinnerProv = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinnerKota = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinnerKec = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner3);
    spinnerDesa = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner4);
    // spinner item select listener
    spinnerProv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            try {
                mSelected = URLEncoder.encode(categoriesList.get(position).getId().toString(), "utf-8");
                URL_KOTA ="http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/kota/id/"+mSelected+"/format/json";
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                            mSelected + " Selected" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new GetKota().execute();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
    // spinner item select listener
    new GetCategories().execute();
}

public void login_cancel_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(1);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void regis_cancel_click(View view)
{       
    main.setVisibility(1);
    login.setVisibility(-5);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

public void login_accept_click(View view)
{
    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);

    new Login().execute();

}

public void regis_accept_click(View view)
{

    main.setVisibility(-5);
    login.setVisibility(1);
    regis.setVisibility(-5);
}

private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Validating User..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {

        String username = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
        if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
        // Preparing post params
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();

        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_LOGIN,
                ServiceHandler.POST, params);

        Log.d("Create Response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                // checking for error node in json
                if (jsonObj.getString(KEY_LOGIN) != null) { 
                    // new category created successfully
                    JSONArray menuitemArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("login");
                    for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
                        String id = menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_user").toString();
                        String email = menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("email").toString();
                        session.createLoginSession(""+id, ""+email.toString());
                    }
                    // Staring MainActivity
                    Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(a);
                    finish();

                } 

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Email Atau Password Salah", false);
                    }
                }); 
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        }else{
            // user didn't entered username or password
            // Show alert asking him to enter the details
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
            alert.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login failed..", "Masukan Email dan Password", false);
                }
            }); 
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerProv.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

private void populateSpinnerKota() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesListKota.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesListKota.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerKota.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}

private class GetCategories extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_PROV, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("lokasi");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getString("id_provinsi"),
                                catObj.getString("nama"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateSpinner();
    }

}

private class GetKota extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_KOTA, ServiceHandler.GET);
        categoriesListKota.clear();
        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categorieskota = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("lokasi");                        

                    for (int i = 0; i < categorieskota.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categorieskota.get(i);                         
                        Category catK = new Category(catObj.getString("id_kota"),
                                catObj.getString("nama"));
                        categoriesListKota.add(catK);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateSpinnerKota();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these code:

```
private static String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
private String URL_LOGIN = "http://api.omidev.com/login/format/json";
private String URL_PROV = "http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/provinsi/format/json";
```

to:

```
private static final String KEY_LOGIN = "login";
private static final String URL_LOGIN = "http://api.omidev.com/login/format/json";
private static final String URL_PROV = "http://api.omidev.com/lokasi/jenis_lokasi/provinsi/format/json";
```

See the difference. The second using `static final`. Then, change `void` to `String` while using `String` parameter. For example:

```
private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

// Change void to String if the first AsyncTask parameter is a String.
// If the first parameter is Void, change to void (in lowercase)
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) { // Must be a String type, because the first parameter type is a String.
```

Comment: my error code not in Login aynctask but in GetKota asynctask

Comment: That is an example only for you. I think, you need to learn more about `AsyncTask`. See edit.

Comment: I just try it but give same error with my last code